# How to call default helper method from own helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I want to call `number_with_precision` method in my helper method like this:

```
module CompaniesHelper
    def number_formatter(number, options={})
        number_with_precision(number, options{})
    end
end
```

But in rails console it doesn't work.

```
pry(main)> helper.number_formatter(3, precision: 2)
=> nil
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the module you want to use.

```
pry(main)> include CompaniesHelper
pry(main)> number_formatter(3, precision: 2)
```

I have not tried it yet. But it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it returns still `nil`. But you make me notice that I must specify `CompaniesHelper`. `CompaniesHelper.number_formatter(3, precision: 2)` invoke right method. There is still method error though.

Comment: Sorry, my comments were wrong. your way works when I restart rails console, I have still no idea why `reload!` did not work.